# Is "Player" interchangeable with "Planeswalker"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Cards the say target player, but say nothing about Planeswalkers such as those printed before Planeswalkers were a thing. Can i target a planeswalker in place of a player?

Answer (score 3):

No, a planeswalker cannot be targeted by a card unless explicitly stated; however, they can be damaged by cards that target players.

This is called the Planeswalker redirection rule:

> 306.7. If noncombat damage would be dealt to a player by a source controlled by an opponent, that opponent may have that source deal that damage to a planeswalker the first player controls instead. This is a redirection effect (see rule 614.9) and is subject to the normal rules for ordering replacement effects (see rule 616). The opponent chooses whether to redirect the damage as the redirection effect is applied.

So, anything that can damage a player has been pseudo-errata'd to be able to damage a planeswalker.

Comment: As i thought, it makes sense to say non-combat damage. Planeswalkers can't "Gain X Life" or "Draw a Card"... Thank you. Would you be so awesome as to include 614.9 and 616 too? (Anyone? Moderator?)

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen Those rules just describe how to actually do the redirection.  Why you are able to do it comes from 306.7.

Comment: because it would increase the overall quality of the answer.

Comment: I suppose it would make the answer more useful to quote or link to those rules, but I do believe this post in its current form constitutes a complete answer to the question. It's easy enough to [look up the rules](http://www.yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/).

Answer (score 3):

A Player is *not* a Planeswalker (although they are representing one, thematically).

It really depends of the target qualifier of the spell or ability in question. You can direct *noncombat* damage that would hit a player to a Planeswalker they control.

From the [MtG Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_21031101.pdf)

> 306.7. If noncombat damage would be dealt to a player by a source controlled by an opponent, that opponent may have that source deal
>   that damage to a planeswalker the first player controls instead. This
>   is a redirection effect (see rule 614.9) and is subject to the normal
>   rules for ordering replacement effects (see rule 616). The opponent
>   chooses whether to redirect the damage as the redirection effect is
>   applied.

Comment: Is there a rule that states out that a player isn't a Planeswalker? Or is there just no rule that says otherwise?

Comment: Rule 102.1 defines a Player as one of the people in the game. Rule 110.4 defines a Planeswalker as a Type of Permanent, which is a card. Rule 306.7 removes the "Planeswalker Redirection" rule and specifies that Planeswalkers can be targeted directly.